# Using algorithm, algpseudocode, and algorithm2e packages altogether

Tags: algorithms, incompatibility, algorithm2e

I have to use `algorithm`, `algpseudocode`, and `algorithm2e` packages altogether. I got the following error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   \ALG@b@2@EndIf@0 
l.79        \EndIf

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Does anybody know how to handle this situation?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Finding $z$ based on $w$}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{ZWGameMA}{$\mathcal{A}$}  
      \State $v \in \{0,1\}^\lambda$ is a random input; 
      \State $\mathcal{S} \leftarrow \mathcal{A}(1^\lambda)$;
      \State $w \in \{0,1\}^\lambda$ is a random input;
      \If{${\cal S}(w)= vw$}
        \State $b = 1$;
      \Else
        \State $b = 0$;
        % I got error here, and I know it is because of the package conflict
      \EndIf
      \State Return $b$;
    \EndFunction
    \State /*On input $w$, an optimal $\mathcal{S}$ outputs a $z$ which maximizes $|\{v : z = vw\}|$.*/
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: *Why* do you need to use both [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)?

Comment: @Werner Because, I have several papers that I have to assemble them into my dissertation and unfortunately, I have used all these packages in my papers (not all at one paper).

Comment: @Reza: For the sake of consistency, it seems better to rewrite all the algorithms to look the same, and therefore use only one algorithm package, like either [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) *or* [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e).